# single query to print all the rows whose count is greater than 10

Tags: mysql

I have a table named Table1 whose definition is as below.

```
Id  int False   
Source  nvarchar(MAX)   True    
Dest    nvarchar(MAX)   True    
Port    nvarchar(MAX)   True    
DgmLen  nvarchar(MAX)   True    
Flags   nvarchar(MAX)   True    
Payload nvarchar(MAX)   True
```

Now I want to print all the rows of this table whose "source" count is greater than 10.

Firstly I have used this query to fetch the count of sources in the table:

```
Select Source,count(*) t_count from Table1 group by Source
```

and it has has fetched the following data:

```
Source            t_count
2-170.125.32.3  1
2-172.125.32.10 1
2-190.125.32.10 11
2-190.125.32.3  1
2-192.125.32.10 1
2-192.125.32.3  6
```

Now I want to print all the rows having "Source = 2-190.125.32.10" as its t_count is greater than 10.

How can write this in a **single query**.

Comment: @Paizo mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly, then :-

```
select * from Table1 where Source in
(
Select Source from Table1 group by Source having count(*) > 10
)
```

This return all those rows from `Table1` who have the `Source` column value appearing more than 10 times.

**EDIT :-**

```
select * from Table1 t1 join
(Select Source, Dest from Table1 group by Source, Dest having count(*) > 10) t2
on t1.Source = t2.Source and t1.Dest = t2.Dest
```

Here, the table t2 returns combination of `Source, Dest` appearing more than 10 times and joins it with the base table `Table1`.

Comment: how can I add one more column here along with Source.
I want a combination of rows with uniique "Source and Dest" fields

Answer (score 0):

> having "Source = 2-190.125.32.10"

that's the Keyword: `having`:

```
Select Source,count(*) t_count from Table1 group by Source HAVING t_count > 10
```

and btw: if you are grouping by Soruce - there will be ALWAYS exactly one Result Row, that matches a *certain* source - that's the point of grouping.

Comment: I want to print to entire row, the query above is giving me source and count alone, I don't want count to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your single query should be like this

```
Select Source,count(*) t_count from Table1 group by Source HAVING t_count > 10
```

Similar [EXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90427/16) made

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
s.Source,
s.Dest,
s.Port,
s.DgmLen,
s.Flags,
s.Payload
from Table1 s
join
(
  select 
  source,
  count(*) as tot
  from Table1
  group by source
  having tot > 10
)s1
on s1.source = s.source
```